# What prank is my friend implying?

Tags: cipher, humor

On April Fools, my friend has given me a sentence and said it's a prank, but I didn't understand it.

I asked "What is this?", he mentioned "A joke.", so I was confused what he meant as a joke.

It says:

> //3\\32 60////4 6!\\3 '/0L| L||*, //3\\32 60////4 137 '/0L| |]0\\\//, //3\\32 60////4 2L|// 420L|//|] 4//|] |]35327 '/0L|.

I had to decipher it to get the joke. Can you tell me what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is a reference to

> [a viral internet video that recently got an AI generated resolution upgrade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxqLsrlakK8).

The cipher is a variation of

> [L33tsp34k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet),

which makes it relatively simple to read once you get the basic idea, and since it has several repeating parts, deciphering even the more uncommon character shapes isn't all that difficult.

Comment: Damn, my friend pranked me like that.

Comment: I got rickrolled from this answer, thanks a lot *places face in hands*